# How can I make my crawler do recursive call?

Tags: vba, recursion, web-scraping

Is it possible to make a crawler do recursion in VBA? I've tried to do with a piece of code but as soon as it finds the line within the dotted mark area in my code it throws error showing "wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment". As I'm not an expert in VBA, I can't do that but I suppose there might be any way applying which it is possible.

```
Sub NEWAPPS()
Dim http As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, html As New HTMLDocument
Dim Items As Object, Item As Object, Newitem As Object, elem As Object
Dim Z As String

With http
    .Open "GET", "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/candy-crush-saga/id553834731?mt=8", False
    .send
    html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With

Set Items = html.getElementsByClassName("left")
Set Newitem = html.getElementsByClassName("name")
    For Each Item In Items
        x = x + 1
        If Item.getElementsByTagName("h1").Length Then _
        Cells(x, 1) = Item.getElementsByTagName("h1")(0).innerText

        If Item.getElementsByTagName("h2").Length Then _
        Cells(x, 2) = Item.getElementsByTagName("h2")(0).innerText
    Next Item

    For Each elem In Newitem
        Z = elem.href
    '---------------------
        NEWAPPS (Z)
    '---------------------
    Next elem
End Sub
```

Comment: You can't call `NEWAPPS (Z)` like this (with an argument) since you did not declare Z in your sub as an argument.  Also your code seems to have repeating outputs. Do you want distinct outputs and stop where there is no more unique output? or do you want to extract the same output, like *candy crush saga*, over and over from different urls?

Comment: Thanks Tehscript for your comment. Definitely, the output has to be unique. The serious mistake I've made and you have pointed out is that even if I had been able to make my code run the output would have been candy crush over and over again as the main url is hardcoded. Anyways, it was a rough sketch with mistakes although i don't know if recursion is possible in vba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a recursive sub and call it from another sub. However you are scraping iTunes apps so it must be a huge source and take long time.

To skip visiting same urls and avoid vicious circle, I used dictionary, and the values you are looking for are stored in it as well as in excel cells.

Here is the working code for you to get started. You might want to alter the code depending on how or when you need to stop it.

```
Public dict As Object

Sub NEWAPPS(Z As String)
Dim http As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, html As New HTMLDocument
Dim Items As Object, Item As Object, Newitem As Object, elem As Object

With http
    .Open "GET", Z, False
    .send
    html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With

Set Newitem = html.getElementsByClassName("name")
Set Items = html.getElementsByClassName("left")

If Not dict.Exists(Z) Then
    dict(Z) = Items(1).innerText 'key is url and value is app name and developer
    Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Z 'url
    Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Split(Items(1).innerText, vbLf)(0) 'app name
    Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Split(Items(1).innerText, vbLf)(1) 'developer
End If

For Each elem In Newitem
    If Not dict.Exists(elem.href) Then 'skip visiting same urls and avoid vicious circle
        NEWAPPS (elem.href)
    End If
Next elem
End Sub

Sub RecursiveCrawler()
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
NEWAPPS ("https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/toy-blast/id890378044?mt=8")
'###You can get stored keys and values once the scraping is finished. If it ever finishes:)###
'Dim key As Variant
'For Each key In dict.Keys
'    Debug.Print key 'url
'    Debug.Print Split(dict(key), vbLf)(0) 'app name
'    Debug.Print Split(dict(key), vbLf)(0) 'developer
'Next key
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tehscript, for such a unique solution I never dreamed of until I saw it working. It is very unfortunate that I could not press the upvote button zillion times. Thanks again.